# Excel VBA Loop through Column to Copy and Paste Non Blanks to 3 other Columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and have run into a road block. I am not receiving any errors when I run this and I am unsure where to even start...

I would like to search column C and if there is a non blank copy that value to columns (D,G,I) of the same worksheet.  I would start the searching in Row 4.

I've tried stepping through the code and I'm pretty sure my error is with currVal = ws.Cells(i, "c").  When I step through, nothing happens on the excel sheet (no cells are copied or pasted).

Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated! I've been looking at this all morning.

```
Sub Copy()

Dim lastC As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim currVal As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastC = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To lastC
currVal = ws.Cells(i, "c")
   If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
       currVal = ws.Cells(i, "D")
       currVal = ws.Cells(i, "G")
       currVal = ws.Cells(i, "I")
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Actual results is nothing happens (at least that I can see) and with no errors giving me a place to start looking!

Expected Results would be copying this into 3 additional columns.  The result is an actual formula.  The formula is what i need to be copied.

5/27/2019 9:39 --- value

='15_2019-02_003.CSV'!$A$2  -- formula

I have addressed the formula updating and removing references to the CSV file once the value is pulled from original CSV File.  The purpose of this code is only to search blanks and copy/paste.[Picture of Excel WS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JBMl.png)

Comment: You are allocating the value from those cells to the variable... i think you should do it the other way around, i.e.: `ws.Cells(i, "D").value = currVal`

Comment: This `lastC = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, if you don't qualify `Rows.Count` it will automatically be `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` ... in this case might not make any difference, but keep in mind for future, it should be `lastC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Oh, thank your for your quick response.  When I change that, the macro runs!!  Yay, first time it's run.  But now, it deletes what is in column C and nothing is copied?

Comment: Did you swap `currVal = ws.Cells(i, "c")` too? That was fine... just the other 3 where you want to write the value back to the cells, it should be `cell = value`, not `value = cell`.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!  Yes, that's exactly what i did wrong!  thank you so much for helping!   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the comments, this is how I would have written that particular code, maybe it helps:

```vb
Sub Copy()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim lastC As Long: lastC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim R As Long 'I like to use R (rows) & C (cols), just because makes it more readable (for me)

    For R = 4 To lastC
        With ws
            If .Cells(R, "A").Value <> "" Then
                .Cells(R, "D") = .Cells(R, "C").Value
                .Cells(R, "G") = .Cells(R, "C").Value
                .Cells(R, "I") = .Cells(R, "C").Value
            End If
        End With
    Next R

End Sub
```

PS: I prefer numbers instead of letters for `.Cells` reference, but in this case is understandable to use letter. Just for best practice - readability wise, shouldn't mix them.

Comment: and if you needed to paste the formulas?  is there a simple way to xlpaste.formulas?  And I do really like the R for rows, makes so much more sense!  Thank you for all your help with this.

Comment: You can use `range.Value` for values, `range.formula` for formulas, etc.